# Proving language properties

Tags: math, algebra, language-theory

I am taking a course on the formal foundations of programming, one of things we have covered is proving certain properties of languages, i have done most of the work, but I am stuck on these two questions, as I have no idea how to prove them.

they are as follows:

A ^ (B ^ C) = (A ^ B) ^ C              (which I believe is the associative rule)

A ^ (B U C) = (A ^ B) U ( A ^ C)       (Distribution rule)

In these examples i have used the ^ to mean concatenation

Comment: If you've found what you need you should think of accepting the answer or ask for more details .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

A^B is all the words x such that there is v in A and w in B such that x = vw

> **let's prove A^(B^C) is included into (A^B)^C**
>
> The A^(B^C) is all the words x such that there is v in A and w in B^C
>   such that x=vw
>
> and w = lm where l is in B and m is in C then x=vlm
>
> x=(vl)m =v(lm) since vl is in A^B qnd m is in C then x is in (A^B)^C.
>
> then    **A^(B^C) is included into (A^B)^C.**
>
> Same proof for inverse inclusion
>
> then  **A^(B^C) =(A^B)^C**

**Second:**

x in B U C if and only if x is in B or x is in C.

> **first inclusion:**
>
> if **x in A ^ (B U C)**
>
> then x = vw where v in A and w in B or C
>
> Then x is in A^B or A^C
>
> then **x is in  (A ^ B) U ( A ^ C)**

**second inclusion**

> if **x is in (A ^ B) U ( A ^ C)**
>
> then x = vw with v in A and w in B or x =vw with  with v in A and w in
>   C
>
> then since v is always is A
>
> then x = vw where v in A and w in B or C
>
> **x in  A ^ (B U C)**

Therefore `A ^ (B U C) = (A ^ B) U ( A ^ C)`